# ls --color=auto, why they offer such an option since there is --color=always by default?

Tags: ls, colors

From `man ls`:

```
With --color=auto,
       ls emits color codes only when standard output is connected to a terminal.
```

Just being curious. What would hurt if I emits color when standard output is not connected to a terminal?

Becasue emitting color needs extra computation so if standard ouput isn't connected to a terminal, we don't need that and can save some computations?

Comment: your title Q and body Q seem to differ — but as for the body, coloration is via escape sequences and the program on the other end of a pipe might not deal with them as you expect

Comment: @Fox Yes, I get it now. :)

Comment: There is no defaults. In many shell setups, your `~/.bashrc` is defining  `ls` as some `alias`. Try using `/bin/ls`

Answer (score 5):

I get it now.

What `color codes` means is that `ls --color=always` would output some extra text describing colors and normally the terminal would eat up these texts.

However, when `ls --color=always > test.txt`, the addtional text describing colors would be preserved and saved.

Try `ls --color=always > file1.txt` and `ls --color=auto > file2.txt` and open both files e.g. with `nano` and you can see the differences.